# Preventing an event raised by a built-in function

Tags: vb.net, listview, event-handling

I have this event handler bound to my listview

`ListView1.ColumnWidthChanged`

And I have this function which alters my columns' dimensions executed right after feeding my list with data.

```
ListView1.AutoResizeColumns
```

I want to know if there is a way to suspend VB from firing an event after an automatic sorting ? I mean anything but manual intervention ?

I though about setting a global variable but this takes much work and can be imprecise, also event args parameter doesn't encompass anything implicit that handles a mouse event, Is there any way through ?

This is what I have tried so far about mouse event handling:

```
    Sub listview1mousedown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseMove
        AddHandler ListView1.ColumnWidthChanged, AddressOf resizetable
    End Sub
    Sub listview1mouseup(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseLeave
        RemoveHandler ListView1.ColumnWidthChanged, AddressOf resizetable
    End Sub
```

Is there any peer solution concerning events triggered by other means rather than mouse ?

Comment: By "research command" do you mean you have a command/button called research? If so, I would suggest doing the `RemoveHandler` at the start of that method, and once you are done, you can then call `AddHandler` to re-hook your event handler.

Comment: @Fabulous  yes, but my list is set to autoadjust property after each data loading, that triggers the event automatically the thing i want to escape

Comment: I guess I the Add and `RemoveHandler` code example you put with mouse events made me misunderstand your intentions. You could try `RemoveHandler` just before the code that adds the data and as soon as you are done, you can do the `AddHandler` bit again.

Comment: @Fabulous do you ave an idea how many lines i will interfer to ??? that wil be an ordal I just want an automatic hook that acts like a sinkhole .

Comment: My suggestion was based on the assumption that you are adding data from one method, in which case it would involve adding just the 2 lines. Without more code to look at, I'm afraid I cannot assist further.

Comment: as to mouse eventriggerer, that was aiming to capture mouse moves inside my listview control and set on/off eventhandlers repectively when it enter/leaves

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you add code showing how you are loading your data and what event you are trying to cancel and when you want it canceled.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins I solely want to know if is there anything implicit  within eventargs that shows if the column width is altered following a user defined behavior or a systematic/automatic behavior, I tried to raise event `columnwidthchanging` but there is not any criterion which underlies the origin of that event thus i can't decide whether i cancel it or not

Comment: No, there isn't. If you issue is happening when you load data, then remove the easiest thing is to remove the handler before the load and add it back after the load is complete. If you explain what you are trying to actually accomplish there is probable an alternate method to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it finally, ....

Appearently setting cursor event catch doesn't work literally at the header's level, the function doesn't fire any event when the mouse gets off the higher bound of subitem collection's container, therefor I managed te set focus event listener to catch mouse focus on the listview, this is enough user defined behavior for me:

I set:

```
 AddHandler CType(list, ListView).GotFocus, Sub()
                                                AddHandler CType(list, ListView).ColumnWidthChanged, AddressOf resizetable
                                                Debug.Print("handler on")
                                            End Sub
 AddHandler CType(list, ListView).LostFocus,Sub()
                                                RemoveHandler CType(list, ListView).ColumnWidthChanged, AddressOf resizetable
                                                Debug.Print("handler off")
                                            End Sub
```

Then i wrote in my `Main()`:

```
Public Function resizetable( table As listview, e As columnwidthchangedeventargs)
        '... core of the event handler
        Debug.Print("Listview column width changed")
End Function
```

So i ran my app in debug mode and proceeded to adjust my column size manually, then I saw this in my debug console:

> handler on
>
> Listview column width changed
>
> handler off

I ran this inside `main()`:

```
list.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
```

Nothing appeared in my output !!!! I think I got it right. thanks to everyone for their deliberate advices.